# The Second-largest Unique element in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, if-statement, logic

I am trying to find the second-largest number in an array. Can someone please tell me what condition I am missing?

I am sure there are many solutions available on the internet, but I would like to know what condition I might be missing in my code? (*No Sorting*)

```
class Solution {
    int print2largest(int numbers[], int n) {
        if(n <= 1)
            return -1;
            
        int firstLargeNo = -1, secondLargeNo = -1;

        if(numbers[0] > numbers[1]) {
            firstLargeNo = numbers[0];
            secondLargeNo = numbers[1];
        }
        else {
            firstLargeNo = numbers[1];
            secondLargeNo = numbers[0];
        }
        
        for(int i = 2; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if(numbers[i] > firstLargeNo) {
                secondLargeNo = firstLargeNo;
                firstLargeNo = numbers[i];
            }
            else if(firstLargeNo == secondLargeNo || numbers[i] > secondLargeNo)
                secondLargeNo = numbers[i];
        }
        
        if(firstLargeNo == secondLargeNo)
            return -1;
        
        return secondLargeNo;
    }
}
```

*Failing Test Case File* (Google Drive): [test case](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XikCqVa0QF8svfjisjwHUtmiMIxE5m9P/view?usp=sharing)

*Correct outpu*t: `999`

Comment: Can you provide an example input for which the program doesn't return the correct answer?

Comment: @AddeusExMachina I was practicing on GeeksForGeeks and the size of the input for which it failed was 7000 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking the second-largest **unique** number in the array.

The first case when you can get `firstLargeNo == secondLargeNo` is at the moment of initialization, which can lead to an incorrect result if `secondLargeNo` will not get a chance to be reassigned (*it would be the case when two largest values would be located at the very beginning of the array, e.g.* `{8, 8, 3, 1, 5}`).

If two first elements of the array are *equal*, condition `numbers[0] > numbers[1]` would be evaluated to `false` and the block of code after `else` will be executed:

```
else {
    firstLargeNo = numbers[1];
    secondLargeNo = numbers[0]; // when numbers[1] == numbers[0], secondLargeNo become equal to firstLargeNo instead of being assign to -1
}
```

We can change the initialization of these variables like this:

```
int firstLargeNo = Math.max(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
int secondLargeNo = 
    numbers[0] == numbers[1] ? -1 : Math.min(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
```

Another mistake is rooted in the `else if` condition inside the loop. Checking  `firstLargeNo == secondLargeNo` in not correct, instead we need to check whether next element `numbers[i]` is equal to `firstLargeNo` (*and if it is the case we should skip this element*).

The rest of the code can be written like this:

```
for(int i = 2; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if(numbers[i] > firstLargeNo) {
        secondLargeNo = firstLargeNo;
        firstLargeNo = numbers[i];
    }
    else if (numbers[i] != firstLargeNo && numbers[i] > secondLargeNo) {
        secondLargeNo = numbers[i];
    }
}
return secondLargeNo;
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/s4H)

Comment: thanks for replying but I am still not getting the correct output.

Comment: @AmanAgarwal Can add the sample of *input/output* to the question?

Comment: I have added the link to the test case check please check.

Comment: @AmanAgarwal Updated the answer, it gives `999` as required. [*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/s4H)

Comment: Thank You I understood why I was getting the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

why are you starting i=2? because the array isn't sorting.
initial values
firstLargeNo=number[0] and secondLargeNo=number[0];
so get i=1;

Comment: Getting the same output as before.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this solution:

```
class Solution {
int print2largest(int numbers[], int n) {
    if(n <= 1)
        return -1;

    int secondLargeNo = -1, largest = numbers[0];

    for(int num : numbers) {
        if(num > largest) {
            secondLargeNo = largest;
            largest = num;
        }
    }

    return secondLargeNo;
}
}
```

It returns the second largest number in the array if it exists, otherwise it returns -1.

Comment: Failing test cases

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int secondLargest(int [] src) {
    Integer highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    Integer second = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i : src) {
        if (i > highest) {
            second = highest;
            highest = i;
            continue;
        }

        if (i > second) {
            second = i;
        }
    }

    return second;
}
```

Comment: Incorrect Output

Comment: Then you did something wrong. I'm using a randomized list of values form 0-999 and I get 998 every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
int print2largest(int numbers[], int n) {
    if(n <= 1)
        return -1;

  int largest = numbers[0];
  int l_i=0;
   for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        
       for(int j=i+1; j<n-1; j++) {
           if(largest<numbers[j]) {
               largest=numbers[j];
               l_i=j;
        
           } 
       }
           int temp=numbers[i];
           numbers[i]=numbers[l_i];
           numbers[l_i]=temp;
           largest=0;
           
           
   }

    return numbers[1];
}
```

use this solution. first, sort the array in descending order
after that return the second element in the array.

Comment: use this solution